# Search Position of a word in String

Tags: r

I need to do a small exercise in R and I need to know how many times that one specific word appears in string and wherein the position of each of the words.

I have this:

```
string = 'a b a b c d a a g'
splitstring = strsplit(string, '  ')
sapply(gregexpr("a", splitstring, fixed= TRUE), function(x) sum(x>-1))
```

My output is: `[1] 4`, so I have four 'a' in my string and now I wanted to know their position.

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work? You could try `grepl("a", splitstring)`

Comment: I wonder if you checked your code upon running. `splitstring = strsplit(string, '  ')` didn't work JFY. You would get the same result for just `gregexpr("a", string, fixed = TRUE)`. And running `sapply` on vectorized operations is just a waste. And if you already on that path, you don't need regex after splitting. You could do `splitstring <- strsplit(string, ' ', fixed = TRUE)[[1]] ; sum(splitstring == "a") ; which(splitstring == "a")` in order to answer both of your questions in a vectorized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gregexpr` gives you the positions:

```
gregexpr("a", string, f=T)[[1]]
# [1]  1  5 13 15
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using the `stringr` packages location function as follows:

```
library(stringr)
string = 'a b a b c d a a g'
l <- str_locate_all(string, 'a')
l
```

This gives an output in the form of a list of matrix(ces) of all start and end positions as follows:

```
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1   1
[2,]     5   5
[3,]    13  13
[4,]    15  15
```

If you want to extract just the start positions, you can do as follows:

```
l[[1]][, 'start']
[1]  1  5 13 15
```